# To compute integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(Ax)e^{i \langle y,x \rangle}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous function such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(x)|dx < \infty$. Let $A$ be a real $n\times n$ invertible matrix, let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then show that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(Ax)e^{i \langle y,x \rangle}dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)e^{i \langle (A^{-1})^Ty,x \rangle}\frac{dx}{|det \ A|}$$
>   where $\langle y,x \rangle$  is the standard inner product.

I don't know how to tackle this problem. Can anyone help to get started.

Answer (score 1):

It is a change of variable problem since $A(\mathbb R^n)=\mathbb R^n$ you have that $\int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x)dx=\int_{\mathbb R^n} f(Ax) |\det A |dx$. Apply that to the right hand side and notice that then in the inner product $(A^{-1})^T$ and $A$ cancel.

Comment: I understood the change of variable part. How does $(A^{-1})^T$ cancel?

Comment: So the standard inner product is $y^Tx$ then $((A({-1})^Ty)^T(Ax)=y^T(A^{-1})Ax=y^Tx$ since the double transpose is just the starting matrix